What is the best method for installing runner rug on tile staircase?
Husband and I bought a house recently and ripped up the hideous green carpet that was previously on the stairs. We were fortunate to find the stairs are red terra cotta Saltillo tiles and in decent condition. We plan to restore/clean the tiles and place a runner rug on the staircase instead of wall to wall carpeting.
What is the best method for installing a runner rug on tile stairs? Ideally, we don't want to drill or make big holes in the tiles and it looks like staple guns are typically only used to install rugs on wooden staircases. Thoughts on this?

The best method is not to install a runner rug at all.  Choosing to do so will involve holes for the rods to hold it in place, unless you go with an even-more-obnoxious-when-removed adhesive application.

Stuff on stairs you do not want to move when walking up/down.  Preventing movement requires screws/eyes/adhesive, to keep in place.  How was the wall to wall held in place before?  If the tiles are nice, I will second @Ecnerwal's comment, no runners.

@crip659 the wall to wall carpeting was installed by gluing wood pieces onto the tiles in order for the nails to be hammered into the wood. It also looked like they used a carpet glue or some kind of other adhesive on the tiles themselves to glue seal down the carpet. The tiles are actually in okay shape, we'd need to get them professionally restored and cleaned up but our main concern is slipping on the tiles at any point.

You would need almost the same system for a runner carpet.  Will probably need to clean the old adhesive to use new adhesive.  Are the tiles slippery now?

If you like the look of the Saltillo, why cover it?
If you must cover it with carpet, the carpeting must be anchored and this will require glue.  You should talk to your local carpeting store. Ask what glue they recommend for your situation.  You must have a good lasting bond so the carpet runner does not loosen and become dangerous.
Saltillo usually has a heavy sealer on the surface. If needed in the future the glue should be able to be removed with little damage to the tile.  But again this is part of the tile that you prefer to cover with a carpet, so the look of the covered tile should be inconsequential.
